# How to find 3x3 transformation matrix given two set of 3 points.

Tags: matrices

My goal is to find eigenvectors.

Given 2 sets of 3 points (or 2 triangles), like:

T1 =(x,y,z)(x,y,z)(x,y,z)

T2 =(x,y,z)(x,y,z)(x,y,z)

I need to find first the transformation matrix.

NOTE: my situation is specific so I know the triangles share a common center (average of 3 points).

Even more, we can expect that center to always be 0,0,0 .

How can I find the transformation matrix?
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\
 \end{pmatrix}

I've already found examples to do triangle mapping, but I need to simplify the whole process, that's why we can expect no global translation (0,0,0 is always transformed to 0,0,0).

(Excuse me if my question is badly written and formatted...)

I've got the feeling this could/should be with shearing only and no rotation at all, but I'm probably wrong here...

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).